# Making texts appear one by one (aka Typewriter effect) in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

It could be a basic question, or I might made my project far ahead of my ability, but I could really use a help on this which took my hours of searching and trying others' code.

My activity includes three fragments using ViewPager2, which I'll be calling them Fragment A, B, and C. Among these, Fragment B will load another unspecified number of fragments. I'll call it Fragment X1, X2... possibly X99 or so. These fragments are where the typewriter effect will be used, so I placed the text animating function on the Fragment B, for I thought it'd be better be where is loading the fragments instead of every Fragment Xn having it.

```
fun TextView.textDisplay(text: Int) {
    val targetstring: Int = text
    if(textanim) {
            for(i in 1..targetstring){
                println(targetstring.toString()[i])
                Thread.sleep(textanimspeed.toLong())
            } // Typewriter effect
    } else {
        println(targetstring)
    } // display texts at once
}
```

There are also some values in Fragment B that I plan to use for setting the texts' size, animating speed, and whether it will be animated or not.

```
var textsize:Byte = 10
var textanimspeed:Byte = 100
var textanim: Boolean = true
```

and then tried to load in Fragment X1.

```
(activity as FragmentB).TextView1.textDisplay(R.string.stringX1)
```

It turns out this line of code is unreachable and "textDisplay" is "unresolved reference".

If I remove receiver parameter "TextView" of textDisplay(text: Int) and the executing code Android studio doesn't say it's unresolved, but it's still unreachable. Above of all, I believe the texts have to be animated inside the TextView. Running the app wouldn't show me any texts.

The second thing I tried is that copying Java code of typewriter effect and paste it so Android studio would automatically convert it into Kotlin. The result had some reds but I got rid of it. I made a new class "TypeWriterView.kt" that has the code below:

```
class TypeWriterView: AppCompatTextView {
  private var mText: CharSequence? = null
  private var mIndex = 0
  private var mDelay: Long = 150 // in ms

  constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
  constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)

  private val mHandler: Handler = Handler()
  private val characterAdder: Runnable = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        text = mText!!.subSequence(0, mIndex++)
        if (mIndex <= mText!!.length) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, mDelay)
        }
    }
  }

  fun animateText(txt: CharSequence?) {
    mText = txt
    mIndex = 0
    text = ""
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(characterAdder)
    mHandler.postDelayed(characterAdder, mDelay)
  }

  fun setCharacterDelay(m: Long) {
    mDelay = m
  }
}
```

and tried it in Fragment X1.

```
    Sc_X1_tv01.setText(R.string.stringX1)
    Sc_X1_tv01.setCharacterDelay(150)
    Sc_X1_tv01.animateText("${R.string.stringX1}")
```

It has no reds, but is still "unreachable" and doesn't show me any texts when ran.

I'm stuck at this point and seeking for help. Thanks for reading and any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A typewriter effect can be done in a single function quite simply using a coroutine, and then you can use it for any TextView without creating any properties.

```
fun TextView.typeWrite(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner, text: String, intervalMs: Long) {
    this@typeWrite.text = ""
    lifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        repeat(text.length) {
            delay(intervalMs)
            this@typeWrite.text = text.take(it + 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// In an Activity:
myTextView.typeWrite(this, "Hello, world!", 33L)

// In a Fragment:
myTextView.typeWrite(viewLifecycleOwner, "Hello, world!", 33L)
```

As for your own code, the first strategy won't work because you must not sleep on the UI thread. Your strategy is similar to mine above, except that `delay()` in a coroutine doesn't sleep the thread you launched it from, but instead suspends the coroutine. I don't see what's wrong with your second attempt, but it might be in code you didn't post. Not sure what you mean by "unreachable".

Comment: Thaks for your help! The unreachable code was because I put them in the wrong place, onCreateView, so I moved them to onCreate, which solved the problem. Now my first attempt and your code, unfortunately, but are still having "Unresolved reference" with "this cast can never succeed" on "as", and my second attempt(the new class one) is even having NPE. Seems bigger problem is somewhrer else. Good thing I learned to use delay(), and I wonder what do I have to put for lifecycleOwner when calling the function?

Comment: The LifecycleOwner is either your Fragment or your Activity. You also need to have the fragment ktx dependency in your build file: `implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5"`

Answer (score 1):

if anyone is still looking. You can do this Without using lifecycleOwner, using ValueAnimator.

```kotlin
fun TextView.animateCharacterByCharacter(text: String, delay: Long = 33L) {
    // Make sure the text is not empty
    if (text.isEmpty()) return

    // Initialize a value animator to iterate over characters
    val charAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, text.length)

    charAnimation.apply {
        this.duration = delay * text.length.toLong()
        this.repeatCount = 0
        addUpdateListener {
            val charCount = it.animatedValue as Int
            val animatedText = text.substring(0, charCount)
            this@animateCharacterByCharacter.text = animatedText
        }
    }

    charAnimation.start()
}
```